# How can tell CDE that my resources are in a specific subdirectory?

Tags: x11, solaris

I am resurrecting an old archive that lived on a Sun Solaris 2.6 box 20-someodd years ago. While I thought I had everything archived, it seems that I missed archiving files like .Xresources, .profile, etc. Oh well, that's gone for good!

That aside, I do want to get the CDE environment back up the way it was and while I did archive the `.dt` directory, it seems that I'm missing some pieces of the puzzle. In particular, the environment was heavily customized (different window border thickness, colors, etc.) which I believe was contained in a subdirectory that had all my resources defined by application, e.g. there is one for Dtterm, another for Dtsession, etc.

I believe I was able to put all these in a subdirectory and then tell Dtwm before it launched that this subdirectory existed and that when Dtterm launched, it would pull those resources from the file in that directory. I *think* it was setting `XAPPLRES` or an environment variable like that, but I can't recall where to set that so CDE picks it up at startup.

So short of unrolling all my resource files into .Xresources, where can I define XAPPLRES or some other environment variable to pick up my resources directory?